# com.google.api import "cannot be resolved" AEM 6.4

Tags: maven, google-api, bundle, aem, dfareporting

I'm trying to add the google DFA reporting api in order to track offline conversions and post view conversions on my website. I believe I have added the dependencies correctly and built the files in maven properly but I am getting a "cannot be resolved error" in the AEM bundles. Does anyone know why this is?
["Cannot be resolved errors"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRgUh.png)

[Project pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAbmg.png)

[Project core pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7XWp.png)

Comment: Please include your code and exception as a text to your question.

Comment: you need to find an osgi bundle packaging of the dependencies and install it on AEM, alternately you can also embed them in your bundle.

Comment: Does it happen on compile time when running mvn clean install or in runtime when you try to load a certain page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[awd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934317/awd) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006566/com-google-api-import-cannot-be-resolved-aem-6-4/60701990#comment106137282_60006566):

> you need to find an osgi bundle packaging of the dependencies and install it on AEM, alternately you can also embed them in your bundle.

I just embedded the google.api dependancies into my project bundle.